# Hilbert class field of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-14})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

The Hilbert Class Field of $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-14})$ is $L=K(\alpha)$, where $\alpha=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-1}$. Then how does one obtain the Hilbert Class field of discriminant as $X^4-X^3+X+1$.

Comment: It may help that the discriminant of $x^4-x^3+x+1$ is 392. So if you adjoin a root of that to $K$ the only ramification can occur at primes lying above $2$ and $7$. I guess you are expected to work out those by hand. Checking that adjoining $\alpha$ gives the same field may be a bit tedious. But the roots of that quartic don't look too bad (only need square roots), so doable.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you very much for the expalnation both here and  at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509643/find-the-minimal-polynomial

Comment: Remember to verify that you get a cyclic degree four extension. The class group of $K$ is cyclic of order four, generated by ${\frak p}=(3,1+\sqrt{-14})$, and the relative Galois group of the Hilbert class field shoud be isomorphic to the class group

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Thank you very much for the wonderful explanation.

Comment: @SushmaPalimar Why don't you check it yourself? $\text{Pic}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-39})=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ with generator $(2,\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{-39}-1))$.

Comment: @SushmaPalimar I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @AlexYoucis, I wanted to find the Hilbert Class field of $K=\mathbb Q{\sqrt{-39}}$, which has degree 4 over $K$, class number of $K$

Comment: duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506753/hilbert-class-field