# Hilbert class field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I got this doubt after going through tables given by Henri Cohen: Advanced topics in Computational number theory on "Hilbert Class Field of Imaginary quadratic field". pg no.539-542, sec 12.1 and a Book by D A Cox on Primes of the form $x^2+n y^2$.
In Cox Book,   Hilbert Class field of $K=Q(\sqrt{-14})$ is computed as 
$L=K(\alpha)$, where $\alpha=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-1}$ and in Cohen's book, the Hilbert Class field of imaginary quadratic field with discriminant $-56$ is calculated as $X^4-X^3+X+1$, so how these two are equal

Comment: that's a strange way to say $\alpha = \sqrt{1+\sqrt2}$. Why would those two fields not be equal ? have you tried solving the quartic, knowing its Galois group is cyclic of order $4$ ?

Comment: changed $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}-1}$ to $\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}+1}$

Comment: @Sushma you have an electronic version of the book : Primes of the Form x + ny by David A Cox

Comment: @Amine, it should be $X^2+ny^2$, I have a hard copy