# Find the minimal polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-14})$. Then what is splitting field of $K(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}-1})$ over $\mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: You mean how to find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-1}$ over $K$?

Comment: minimal polynomial over $\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-1}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Are you asking whether $K(\sqrt{2\sqrt2 -1})$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $x^4-x^3+x+1$?

Comment: Is [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/503262/11619) trying to ask the same question in different words? Please clarify.

Comment: What is your definition for the minimal polynomial of a field? I don't know it.

Comment: The following may help. Write $a_1=(1+i\sqrt7)/2$, $a_2=(1-i\sqrt7)/2$. Then $a_1a_2=2$ and $a_1+a_2=1$. Consequently
$$(x^2-a_1x-1)(x^2-a_2x-1)=x^4-x^3+x+1.$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Thank you very much for clearing the doubt. But could you please explain how did you get 2 equations/ Is there any method to determine them

Comment: Hmm. Still not clear. Polynomials have splitting fields, number fields have Hilbert class fields, individual numbers have minimal polynomials. We are cooking this soup from very different ingredients.

Comment: Mathematica gave me the roots of the quartic. Educated guessing from that point on :-)

Comment: @YACP, question was really to find how $K (\sqrt{-14},\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-1})$ is equal to $x^4-x^3+x+1$, which is the Hilbert Class field of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-14})$